# Obter valor especifico de JSON

Tags: jquery

Possuo uma API que retorna a imagem correspondente de um status, porem estou com dificuldades em pegar apenas o campo 'caminhofoto' na resposta da minha API.

**Resposta da API:**

```
({"code":1,"msg":"OK","details":[{"caminhofoto":"https:\/\/localhost\/sistema\/assets\/images\/status\/pendente.gif"}],"request":"{\"status\":\"pending\"}"})
```

Código que estou usando para pegar o campo caminhofoto:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"https://localhost/sistema/mobileapp/api/getImagemStatus?status=pending",
    data: { get_param: 'caminhofoto' }, 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        //Aqui tento pegar apenas o campo caminhofoto
        var foto = data['caminhofoto'];

        console.log("ENTROU AQUI "+foto)


    },

  });
```

No console recebo o log:
Entrou aqui *undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O caminho foto está dentro de details, na posição 0 do array.

```
console.log(data.details[0].caminhofoto);
```

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado.